# convert isoDatetime to dateTime format

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

```
Date d = new Date()
iso = d.toISOString()
```

it gives = `2019-10-28T11:23:52.384Z`

but I want in `2019-10-28T01:12 (YYYY-MM-DD T HH:MM AM/PM)` only date time with AM/PM

because in mobile view date time getting iso format.

[image]

Comment: Don't you mean, "hh:MM AM/PM" ?

Comment: yes YYYY-MM-DD T hh:MM AM/PM

Answer (score 1):

You can use a javascript library known as [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Using their `format` function you can manipulate the date format to your liking.

for your case, it should be

```js
import moment from "moment"

let date = new Date();
let yyyymmdd = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
let hhmm = moment(date).format("LT");
let ans = yyyymmdd + " T " + hhmm;
```

output:

`2019-10-28 T 6:28 PM`

[codepen](https://codepen.io/s4k1b-the-selector/pen/yLLoewd)

Comment: You can just use `moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD LT")` to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm, A");
```

Or use Constructor

```
 let d = new Date()
 let iso = moment(d).format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm, A");
```

got: `"2019-10-28T08:18, PM"`

notes:

```
2019-10-28T11:23:52.384Z
```

is ISO8601 format
check [wiki](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
or [iso.org](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is this useful?

```js
const pad = num => ("0" + num).slice(-2)
const d = new Date(2019, 9, 28, 3, 1, 1)
const iso = d.toISOString()
let [date, time] = iso.split("T")
const [_, hh, mm, ss, ampm] = new Date(iso).toLocaleTimeString('en-US').match(/(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (\w{2})/)
console.log(date + "T" + pad(hh) + ":" + pad(mm) + " " + ampm)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out the date components and then piece them back in the order you would like.

Hours and meridian will need to be adjusted.

```js
const DateComponenents = (() => {
  const fields = ['YYYY', 'MM', 'DD', 'HH', 'mm', 'ss', 'SSS'];
  const pattern = /^(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{3})Z$/;
  return (date) => {
    return date.toISOString().match(pattern).slice(1).reduce((r, v, i) => {
      return Object.assign(r, { [fields[i]]: v });
    }, {});
  }
})();

function formatDate(date) {
  let c = DateComponenents(date);          // Extract the componenents
  let hours = parseInt(c['HH'], 10);       // Grab the 24-hour piece
  let meridiem = hours < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; // Determine AM or PM
  hours %= 12;                             // Modular 0 - 12
  if (hours === 0) hours = 12;             // Shift 0am to 12am
  hours = ('00' + hours).substr(-2);       // Pad the hours
  return `${c['YYYY']}-${c['MM']}-${c['DD']} T ${hours}:${c['mm']} ${meridiem}`
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is a more dynamic version that supports custom formatting...

```js
const DateComponenents = (() => {
  const fields = ['YYYY', 'MM', 'DD', 'HH', 'mm', 'ss', 'SSS'];
  const pattern = /^(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{3})Z$/;
  const applyRest = (c) => {
      let hours = parseInt(c['HH'], 10);
      let meridiem = hours < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
      hours %= 12; hours = ('00' + (hours === 0 ? 12 : hours)).substr(-2);
      return Object.assign(c, { 'hh' : hours, 'A' : meridiem });
  }
  return (date) => {
    return applyRest(date.toISOString().match(pattern).slice(1).reduce((r, v, i) => {
      return Object.assign(r, { [fields[i]]: v });
    }, {}));
  };
})();

function formatDate(date, format) {
  return (c => format.replace(/\w+/g, key => c[key] || key))(DateComponenents(date));
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD T hh:mm A'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the js standard library [Intl.DateTimeFormat API's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat).  They give you a lot of control and are built-in.

They are new-ish but are supported by all browsers other then MSIE.

```
const options = {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      day: 'numeric',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: 'numeric',
      hour12: true  // Gives you the AM PM
    };
// Note that the 'second' is omitted
// See 'timeZone' and 'timeZoneName' options if you want to control those.

const dateString = new Intl.DateTimeFormat( 'en-ca', options ).format( new Date() );
```

Note that I specified Canadian English for the locale because that is one of the many countries that has adopted ISO 8601 as their recommended format.  The only drawback of 'en-ca' is that it adds a comma but you can just use string.replace to swap that for the 'T'.